# Возможно ли сохранять данные в переменую, и отправление их в файл?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

У меня есть Input, мне надо из него получить данные и получать в переменую, и отправлять в другой файл, и чтоб после даже после перехода на другую страницу данные сохранялись возможно такое? Может надо использивать textarea

```
        <form name="access">
        <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="token">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
      </form>
```

Comment: нет, js/jquery не умеет записывать в файл, так же как и работать с файловой систкмой

Comment: можно только записать в локалсторадж но дальше браузера эта запись не пойдёт

Comment: а php может БД еще надо

Comment: а вот это другое дело, php как раз умеет записывать в файл, генерировать новый файл и т д

Comment: можно еще node.js

Comment: на php.net подробно всё написано, даже с примерами

Comment: у меня есть nodejs

Comment: сможеш помоч???

Comment: с нодой не смогу - но в ютубе напиши так - запись в файл node.js